# Categories of Dhammanupassana (Satipatthana)

Tags: theravada, vipassana, satipatthana

What are the components, the categories (the dhammas)that have to be observed in dhammanupassana (the 4th field of satipatthana)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The categories are:

- 5 hindrances
- 5 aggregates of clinging
- 6 internal and 6 external sense-bases
- 7 awakening-factors
- 4 noble truths

Sourced from: [Mahā Sati’patthāna Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/13.2-Mahasatipatthana-S-d22-piya.pdf)